# ¿Cómo puedo traer un dato desde una tabla de una base de datos y guardarlo en una variable global?

Tags: php5

Estoy aprendiendo a manejar este tema relacionado a base de datos y surgió la curiosidad de que al momento de que yo valido un usuario poder al mismo tiempo obtener el código de ese usuario y grabarlo en una variable global para poder usarla en otra parte al hacer un INSERT INTO, UPDATE o DELETE

lo que tengo es:

```
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM usuarios where USU_USUARIO = '$usuario' and  PASS_USUARIO = '$contrasenia'";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
$filas = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);
```

Justo aquí es donde quisiera saber que se puede hacer para obtener ese dato y guardarlo en una variable que sea global.
Espero me puedan ayudar ya que ni he encontrado algo relacionado a mi inquietud en videos tutoriales.

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo esto:

```
$usuario = $GLOBALS["bd"]->query("SELECT * FROM usuarios where USU_USUARIO = '$usuario' and  PASS_USUARIO = '$contrasenia'")->fetch_assoc();
```

Con esto lo que hace es crear un array con toda la data del primer resultado obtenido es decir para acceder a algun dato por ejemplo id puedes hacerlo asi: `$usuario["id"];`
y si lo que quieres es poder usar esta data en otros php simplemente lo guardas en un $_SESSION;

Nota: Ten en cuenta que fetch_assoc() solo te retorna el primer resultado, asi que tienes que validar bien tu usuario para que no obtengas un registro de otro usuario